# how to kill/stop running processes in python interactive of vscode

Tags: vscode-tasks

I have been using VScode recently, the way I do to stop a running process in python interactive is to close and reopen it, but that seems unwise and cumbersome.

So is there a good way to stop a running process in python interactive as shown below? Do we have any shortcuts to do that?

[image]